# leaflet addPolygons to create countries heatmap using non-json data

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinyjs

I have to read my data from a excel source which contains several columns, of which the first is the name of the country (in French and sometimes in German), and three other columns each of which lists a city from that country. And some more columns which contain extra data for each line.

```
Country        City1    City2   City3   Info1   Info2   Info3
France        name1     name2   name3   info1   info2   info3
Spain                       
Portugal                        
France                      
France                      
Ireland                     
Ireland
```

The name of a country appears several times, and each time the values for the info columns are different.

How can I show a leaflet map with a heatmap-like feature? let's say, the stronger the color, the more the name of that color is repeated in the list, or the stronger the color, the bigger the values in the info columns.

My problem is that my data doesn't contain the geojson coordinates, nor the longitude/latitude values, and the name of the countries are not in English. How can I create a json file out of this data and map it onto the leaflet using addPolygons or the like?

### However:

if needed, or if your proposed solution obliges, I can do the following hacks to my data before feeding it to R:

1. I can convert all of the country names to English.
2. I can add the longitude/latitude of the capital city of that the countries as two extra columns.

Comment: I think for the location problem the magic word you are looking for is "geocoding" - assigning a location to a name or address. There are various services such as Nominatim or Google's geocoder you can use with a script, probably even in R

Comment: @chrki - yes, within `R` the library `ggmap` has a `geocode` function (which uses google's API)